# RestSharp async background thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, restsharp

I'm trying to send some POST requests to a server using RestSharp.  However:

1. The server takes about 20 seconds to process each request
2. I don't want to lock up my GUI whilst I'm waiting for them to finish.

RestSharp has async functionality, so I've written this:

```
var handler = _restClient.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
                {
                    if(response.IsSuccessful)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Success");
                    }
                });
```

What I need to do is ensure that this happens on a separate background thread, as not to lock the GUI, and to wait for each response, check if successful, and then send the next one.

Any suggestions?  A queue of some kind?

Comment: So the "current" request depends on the result of the last one? Or are they independent?

Comment: They are all independent, just the request causes the server some considerable workload, so I don't want to overload it with requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could consider using async/await so as not to lock up the UI thread

```
var response = await _restClient.ExecuteTaskAsync(request);
if(response.IsSuccessful) {
    Console.WriteLine("Success");
}
```

Comment: Just what I needed.  I didn't realise there was a ExecuteTaskAsync in there.  Thanks for pointing that out.